# Both failed rooting LG G6 Nougat 7.0 on one-click root and PC

Tags: root-access, lg

I have been trying to root my LG G6 with Nougat 7.0 on. On the one click method it reaches 90% then fails with an error code: 0x172E55. I can never get past that. Then I tried with the PC version. I turned usb debugging on and use the original wire. It keeps on prompting me to turn on usb debugging and flashes on and off the connecting image. How do I fix this?